# Ford VNR 9000 Radio code

Tags: ford, audio, code

First: Happy New Year for everyone :)

Help me please radio code problem.
I have a car: Ford Scorpio mk2 1996

Model Number: 9000 Ford VNR / VNR Spring MNT
Part Number: 1S7F-18K931-AA
Serial Number: KAEM021238

There is this code? Possibly program? I could not find anywhere. If you can help please.
It can be downloaded from somewhere in the CRUCC, or similar programs?
Thanks
Thomas Staviarszki regards from Hungary

Comment: It sounds like your radio isn't working and is prompting you for a code. Is that right? The code usually (in the US at least) comes with the car and is specific to the particular radio – it is like a password and is supposed to help prevent stealing of the radio. If that is the original radio, you might be able to get the code from a Ford dealer.

Comment: As @dlu stated. Here in the States I can take the VIN to the dealership and they can get me the code. I have to prove I own the car is the only stipulation. Some vehicles (Hondas are one I believe) will have the code written down in the owners manual. You may try there if you have the original manual.

Comment: VW also provides the code in the original papers that you get with the car. I think there is also a spot to write it in the owner's manual. So, if you've got any of the original papers look through those.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate Ford radio code easily from the radio serial number. All you have to do is to remove your radio and find the serial number starting with Mxxxxxx

In your case the serial number is : M021238

Your radio code is : **1471**

Comment: This would be a better answer if you said how to generate the code.

Comment: I just used the method described in this video tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KfNMuFFWpw